# Restful Express API passes in mocha, fails in browser; curl

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have a restful api running on localhost that I've tested in Mocha (which starts the server) - all tests seem to pass.  However, if I try using POSTMAN or curl on the restful urls, it fails (see error at bottom of this page).  I've tried both Firefox and Chrome.

EXPRESS

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));

app.post('/uborrow/items', handlers.items.addItem);

blah blah blah startserver on port 3000
```

SCHEMA

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
name:  { type: String, required: true, index : {unique:true}},
description: String,
thumbnail : Buffer,
waitList : [],
checkoutHistory : [],
currentCheckout : String,
lastCheckoutDate : Date,
availableDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
inactiveDate : Date,
cabinet : ObjectId
});

itemSchema.statics.createItem = function(item, cb) {
console.log("Adding item " + item);
var itemModel = mongoose.model("Item");
new itemModel(item).save( function (err, newItem){
    if (err)  cb(err, null);
    cb(null,newItem);
})
};
```

HANDLER

```
console.log("\nHEADERS - item:" + req.body.item )
  Item.createItem(req.body.item, function(err,item){
  if (err) return res.json(401,err);
    res.json(202,item);
  })
});
```

TESTDATA

```
module.exports = {
"itemData" : {
    availableTrialItem3 : {
        name:"SE 8399-RH-ROCK 11-Inch Rock Pick Hammer",
        description: "Brand new 20 oz. Rock Pick Hammer. This heavy, well balanced hammer has a rubberized hammer for a comfortable grip. This hammer is made of a single-Piece of drop forged metal.",
        availableDate : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-10)),
        waitList : []
    }
}
}
```

TEST

```
var itd = testData.itemData;
it.only("should return 202 item created item via post to /uborrow/items", function(done){
var url = "/uborrow/items"
request(app)
    .post(url)
    .send({item:itd.availableTrialItem3})
    .end(function (err, res) {
        should.not.exist(err);
        res.should.have.status(202)  ;
        res.body.should.property("name").eql(itd.availableTrialItem3.name);
        res.body.should.have.property("waitList").with.length(0);
        done();
    });
});
```

TEST RESULT

```
Express server listening on port 3000
UBorrow API :
-- itema api --
connected to test database
ADDING ITEM
Adding item [object Object]
POST /uborrow/items 202 17ms - 391b
â should return 202 item created item via post to /uborrow/items


1 passing (58ms)
```

POSTMAN

```
POST /uborrow/items HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item"

{name:"NORLAKE 119958 Solar Thermometer, 8' Lead Sensor", description: "119958, THERMOMETER SOLAR WITH 8 FOOT SENSOR LEAD. Norlake Genuine OEM replacement part. Norlake has become a leader in high-quality refrigeration for the commercial foodservice operating. Use genuine OEM parts for safety reliability and performance."}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

RESULT

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {name:"NORLAKE 119958 Solar Thermometer, 8' Lead Sensor",             description: "119958, THERMOMETER SOLAR WITH 8 FOOT SENSOR LEAD. Norlake Genuine OEM replacement part. Norlake has become a leader in high-quality refrigeration for the commercial foodservice operating. Use genuine OEM parts for safety reliability and performance."}
```

Comment: Try adding a Content-Type: application/json header on your POSTMAN request.

Comment: You are the best. I was going crazy with the same issue and it now works :)